# ComboBox1Select(nil)

Tags: delphi-7, combobox

Как вызвать друг за другом `ComboBox1Select(nil)`?

Пример 1 :

```
ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
ComboBox1Select(nil);
ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 1;
ComboBox1Select(nil); 
// Так не получается вызывает последний ItemIndex
```

Пример 2 :

```
for i := 0 to ComboBox1.Items.Count -1 do
begin
ComboBox1.ItemIndex := i;
ComboBox1Select(nil);
end; 
// Так тоже не получается
```

Собственно вопрос, как вызвать все `ComboBox1.ItemIndex` подряд по одному через обращение `ComboBox1Select(nil)` может место `nil` какой то параметр надо поставить?

**Обновление**

Я не хочу все менять, у меня все работает через событие `onselect`. Допустим, `combobox1.itemsindex := 0` и программа выдала результат и так при выборе любого itemsindex-а. Получается результат соответствующий этому `itemsindex`. Мне хотелось бы, не менять весь код, а с другой кнопки обратиться к itemsindex и выбрать по очереди так, чтоб обойти с первого до последнего. К примеру, в цикле или еще как–то. Поэтому я увидел решение, в котором `ComboBox1Select(nil)` может запускать `ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 0;`, но по факту запускает только один раз, а мне нужно все пройти. Выше написал, как пробовал и что не получилось.

Comment: Пожалуйста уточните что именно вы хотите сделать, отформатируйте текст вопроса. И что такое в вашем коде `ComboBox1Select`?

Comment: `ComboBox1Select(ComboBox1);` тоже не работает?

Comment: А что делает ваш `ComboBox1Select`?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не регистрируйтесь как новый пользователь на каждое Ваше сообщение. Постарайтесь внятно объяснить, чего Вы хотите достичь, путем редактирования первоначального вопроса.

Comment: Все прекрасно работает с `ComboBox1Select(nil);` вы напишите в этом событии `ShowMessage('ОК')` и увидите результат. Скорее всего данные просто как Вы говорите формируются очень быстро и виден только последний результат.

Answer (score 1):

Пробуйте так:

```
for i := 0 to ComboBox1.Items.Count -1 do
begin
  ComboBox1.ItemIndex := i;
  ComboBox1Select(nil);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Но это плохое решение. Лучше избегать вызова `Application.ProcessMessages`, т.к. это замедляет работу приложения и может привести к непредсказуемым последствиям.

Comment: ComboBox1Select(ComboBox1); так тоже не работает,срабатывает только один раз

Comment: все равно вызывает самый последний ComboBox1.ItemIndex десятый по счету

Comment: Покажите уже нам, что делает ваш `ComboBox1Select`? Может вы просто не успеваете заметить результата?